# sendmail -v email@email.com returns killed when root

Tags: solaris, sendmail

For some reason some of my Solaris 10 systems won't send mail as root.

If I try to send a test email as a non root user using `sendmail -v` I get a nice long list of details ending in success.

If I try as root it just returns "killed" or ksh: ### Killed

What is going on?